# Viewing original ObjC code instead of assembly in the debugger

Tags: debugging, xcode4.3

Can you please tell me how to see only Objective-C code and not assembly when I use the debugger in Xcode 4.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manually check the type of value or object in the console window. For example you would type `p <object>` or `po <object>` to view it.